# CodeIgniter routes doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I have a problem that looks beast, but googled and can not resolve ... I'm using CodeIgniter and only the route `$ route ['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` is working when I do an example: `$ route ['test'] = "welcome";` it gives me the following message **Can not GET / codeigniter / index.php / test**. Would anyone tell me what can be?

Answer (score 0):

The default controller should not have a slash or space in it.  It just the name of the default controller, so it should be 'Welcome' or 'Othercontroller', etc.

$route['test'] = 'welcome' should work, assuming you have a welcome controller with a defined 'index' action.  Try fixing the first part and see if that helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't work... My default_controller calls the same controller "welcome" and it works, but when I use $route['teste'] calling the same controller "welcome", it show me Cannot GET /codeigniter/index.php/test

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the index.php in the URL like so, assuming your site URL is localhost/mysite;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|_searches|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

configure your base URL

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mysite/';
```

Comment: But the problem is in my routes... the default route works, but my teste route shows Cannot GET /codeigniter/index.php/test. I'm using yeoman with php-cgi to run codeigniter together